# Interesting ways to use the verb frühstücken?

Tags: verb

I just learned about this verb and that it means you are *eating breakfast* so that there is no need to use the word *essen* or a form of *sein* or *haben*. In English we would typically say *I am eating breakfast* or *I am having breakfast* and would rarely just say *I am breakfasting* so I find this German verb interesting. Though there are probably more examples of this type that I just don't know about yet.

Can I ask how native speakers might employ this verb in a longer sentence and if it is just used in the short way 'ich frühstücke' as is?

Comment: I am not quite sure what exactly your questions are. 1) Why do you think the usage of this verb would be special in a longer sentence? 2) Do you want to know whether “Ich frühstücke.” is actually a valid and idiomatic sentence?

Comment: 1. Oddish verb for non-German speakers and I am simply curious abut it. Interested in knowing how native speakers might implement this verb in a longer sentence or in another, quirkier way, especially since it relates to food. 2. Correct. I think most people would understand my questions. I hate spelling things out to death but just added this comment to reply and be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. Note that I am not nagging you for such details and precision for their own sakes. Knowing where your doubts comes from helps us to better answer your question. Keep in mind that many potential answerers are native speakers, to whom *frühstücken* is usually just like any other verb.

Comment: in English it would have to be “I am breaking fast”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The meaning of »frühstücken« is in long sentences the same as in short sentences.

> Ich frühstücke.
>   I’m having breakfast.
>
> Gestern habe ich länger geschlafen und habe daher erst am Nachmittag gefrühstückt.
>   Yesterday I’ve been sleeping longer and so I had my breakfast in the afternoon.

Another verb that is used the same way as »frühstücken« is »jausnen«.

> noun: Das Frühstück (the breakfast) → verb: frühstücken (to have breakfast)
>   noun: Die Jause (the snack) → verb: jausnen (to have a snack)

As far as I know, the noun »Jause« is rarely used in most parts of Germany, so also the verb »jausnen« might be unknown in Germany. But in Austria it is well known.

Comment: Make that "in most parts" - not just in the northern ones, please.

Comment: @ Hubert Schölnast : Please,  "jausnen" is also unknown in Bavaria. You can't extrapolate from Austria the whole German speaking world. Without experience in other parts there one might give not so correct answers.

Comment: @Karl Indeed, especially when it comes to eating and food, Austria is very different from Germany, even Bavaria, see for instance the [Chefkoch dictionary](http://www.chefkoch.de/magazin/artikel/1413,1/Chefkoch/Deutsch-Oesterreichisch-Schweizerische-Kuechenbegriffe.html), which is but one among many.

Comment: Jausnen? Jause? Never heard of it in Hesse.

Comment: Ich habe es korrigiert. Sorry, aber es ist nicht einfach abzuschätzen, wie weit außerhalb des eigenen Lebensraums ein Begriff verbreitet ist. Deutsche, die nach Österreich kommen haben ja dasselbe Problem: Sie verwenden viele Begriffe, die für sie alltäglich sind, die in Österreich aber nicht oder nur selten verwendet werden, ohne zu wissen, dass diese Wörter hierzulande unüblich sind. Wirklich unbekannt sind solche Teutonismen in Österreich aber nicht, weil wir Österreich dem deutschen Deutsch durch Bücher, Zwitschriften und deutsches Fernsehen weit stärker ausgesetzt sind, als umgekehrt.

Comment: Österreichisches Deutsch sickert hingegen kaum nach Deutschland. Es gibt keine Bücher, die in österreichischem Deutsch gedruckt werden (weil die sich im zehnmal größeren bundesdeutschen Buchmarkt nicht verkaufen würden), auch die wenigen österreichischen Zeitschriften, die es gibt, werden meist in deutschen Deutsch geschrieben (weil wir Österreicher das schon gewohnt sind), und österreichisches Fernsehen schaut sich außerhalb Österreichs kaum jemand an. Daher kommen Deutsche mit österreichischem Deutsch nur in Kontakt, wenn sie zu uns migrieren, oder als Tourist herkommen.

Comment: Für einen Österreicher, sind Wörter wie *Sackerl*, *jausnen*, *Spritzer*, *Bartwisch*, *beuteln* usw. ganz alltägliche Begriffe der Standardsprache (also jener Form der Sprache, die in Schulen unterrichtet wird). Und weil diese Wörter so alltäglich sind, ist uns häufig unbekannt, dass diese Wörter woanders nicht verstanden werden. Es gibt ja auch Teutonismen, wie z.B. *Abitur*, *Azubi*, *Omnibus*, *Hörnchen*, *Brühe* usw., die nur in Deutschland verwendet werden. Aber wie oben schon gesagt, werden diese Wörter in Österreich wenigstens (als Wörter einer Fremdsprache) verstanden.

Comment: Schau, und i hab erst denkt, du hättest einen Schreibfehler drin, und *jausen* ohne zweites *n* gemeint, so unbekannt ist das Wort selbst in (West-) Bayern … ;).

Comment: @Jan: Nein, mit *n*. So wie es im Duden steht: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/jausnen

Comment: Ich habe auch deshalb in der ersten Version meiner Antwort »Norden Deutschlands« geschrieben, weil bei ähnlichen Beiträgen meinerseits reflexartig immer irgend jemand etwas in dieser Art gepostet hat: »*Das ist nicht Österreichisch, denn in Bayern gibt's das Wort auch*«, was dann in weiterer Folge gerne als Argument genutzt wurde, um die Existenz eines eigenständigen Österreichischen Deutsch gleich grundsätzlich in Frage zu stellen. Dem wollte ich vorbeugen, doch diesmal war's halt nicht angebracht.

Comment: Noch ein paar Links zum Thema »Jausnen«: Konjugationstabelle: http://www.verbformen.de/konjugation/jausnen.htm Jausnen aus medizinischer Sich: http://www.medizinpopulaer.at/archiv/essen-trinken/details/article/richtig-jausnen.html aus pädagogischer Sicht: http://styriavitalis.at/angebote/anders-jausnen/ im Fremdenverkehr: http://www.landtmann-jausenstation.at/blog/aus-unserer-kueche/idyllisch-jausnen-auf-majestaetischem-boden.html

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Möchte an dieser Stelle auf die wunderbare Christine Nöstlinger verweisen, die keine Scheu hat, österreichische (oder wienerische) Begriffe zu verwenden, die auch in den deutschen Ausgaben ihrer Bücher nicht eigens "übersetzt" werden.

Comment: @Stephie: Ja, auch Wolf Haas und Alfred Komarek schreiben in österreichischem Deutsch, und auch einige Autoren von Krimis, die in Österreich spielen, schreiben in ihrer Muttersprache. Aber das sind Ausnahmen, die außerhalb Österreichs keine nennenswerten Verkaufszahlen erreichen. Nöstlinger, Haas, Komarek usw. werden in Deutschland nur von Menschen gelesen, die ohnehin schon einen besonderen Österreich-Bezug haben. Auf diese Weise wird österreichisches Deutsch in einem geradezu lächerlich geringen Maß nach Deutschland exportiert, verglichen mit dem Import deutschen Deutschs nach Österreich.

Comment: Österreicher, die in Deutschland gelesen werden wollen (Köhlmeier, Jelinek, Franzobel, Glavinic, Glattauer, und viele mehr) schreiben nicht in österreichischem Deutsch, sondern in deutschem Deutsch. Wer als junger unbekannter Autor überhaupt verlegt werden will, und sein Buch in österreichischem Deutsch geschrieben hat, wird von so gut wie jedem Verlag erst mal aufgefordert, es in deutsches Deutsch umzuschreiben. Und wenn's der Autor nicht macht, machen das Lektoren.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Gerade bei Nöstlinger möchte uch widersprechen: Sie gilt als eine der klassischen Kinderbuchautorinen (die Liste der Auszeichnungen belegt das) und so ziemlich jede halbwegs gut sortierte Buchhandlung hat sie im Kinder-/Jugendbuchregal stehen. Wobei ich Dir im Kern (leider) rechtgeben muß.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Es gibt ö. Tatorte, es gibt einige Kabarettisten (Hader, Dorfer, Willkommen Österreich) auf 3sat v.a., Es gab so eine Krimiserie mit 5 Frauen, es gibt Niki Lauda, der sich nicht anscheißt auch mal Traffik oder Paradeiser zu sagen. Wenn die Verleger oder Lektoren meinen, sie müssten die Sprache verstecken - das ist wirklich dumm, denn die paar Wörter und Redewendungen hat man rasch drauf, zumal Ö. auch das beliebteste Ferienland d. D. ist wo man dann beim Heurigen sitzt.  Allerdings hätte ich auch 'jausen' statt 'jausnen' gedacht. In Bayern ja bekanntlich 'brotzeiteln'. ;)

Answer (score 5):

From the meaning it is a bit difficult to construct longer sentences. Two examples nevertheless:

- Ich frühstücke gerne ausgiebig: mit Tee, Orangensaft, frischen Brötchen, Rührei und Speck.
- Unter der Woche habe ich keine Zeit zu frühstücken, da muss eine Tasse Kaffee reichen.

Answer (score 2):

It’s really hard to see what seems to be so special about *frühstücken*, because it is really just a verb like many others, for a close relation to a noun (or adjective) is not unusual at all – in German **and** English. The English verb *breakfast*, derived from the noun (and without *have* or *eat*), is also well attested, in particular.

*frühstücken* is never split, so this is ungrammatic, not least because **stücken* is not a lexicalised verb:

> - * Ich stücke früh.

It may be used without adverbs and objects much of the time, but doesn’t have to:

> - *Ich frühstücke meistens Müsli.*
>     (qualitative adverb and accusative object)
> - *In unserer Familie frühstücken wir jeden Morgen gemeinsam.*
>     (locative, temporal and modal adverbial phrases)
> - *Treffen wir uns Sonntag zum Frühstücken?*
>     (nominalised, also possible: *… Frühstück?*)
> - *Wenn ich nicht richtig gefrühstückt habe, bin ich zu nichts zu gebrauchen.*
> - *Opa verfrühstückt unser Erbe.*
>     (as derivative base, here with metaphoric meaning ‘to squander’)

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely nothing special about *frühstücken*. What maybe surprises you – and from the wording of the question (concretely “so that there is no need to use the word *essen* or a form of *sein* or *haben*”) I deduce you still don’t know it – is that there is no exact *-ing*-analogue, i.e. gerund, in German.

So, you feel like that because one cannot use the verb *frühstücken* with *sein* or *haben* in present (not this, not any other verb) at all.

Comment: @cheznead: please note that we do encourage non-native speakers to contribute with answers. In case they struggle with orthography or grammar we all try to help making their answer better. It is common sense to do that  [with an edit](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/4/editing-orthographic-errors) (also see [this related post](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/289/is-my-edit-appropriate)). In many cases non-natives may have a better approach to specific issues a learner may have than native speakers.

Comment: Not in this case @Takkat as others gave better answers. What c.p. wrote as an 'answer' amounts to what should be a comment. Furthermore, I have had old questions suddenly downvoted after I downvoted this answer by c.p. They have also gone to another question of mine and edited it only to make incorrect changes. This is unacceptable and I am leaving this forum.

Comment: Editing our own posts and posts of other people is one thing what makes us different to an internet forum. All Stack Exchange Q & A sites are mainly driven not by single users but by us, the community. By this we may be closer to a Wiki than to a forum. This also is an important source of our success. Here is more information [on our model](http://german.stackexchange.com/help/stackexchange).